A Mailing Group creation date
Would the log_date column of the log_civicrm_group table be the only source of a mailing group creation date? There is some dates in a "cache_" columns of the "civicrm_group" table, perhaps a part of Smart groups functionality though.

yes i think you are right

@petednz-fuzion Thank you, it was a self-answered question then.

Yes, it turns to be true, therefore enable logging.
